# Django import error when starting sever with pipenv

Tags: python, django, windows, python-3.7, pipenv

I am trying to runserver for my django app on Windows. I used to do it trough Anaconda, but I reinstalled it to Anaconda3 yesterday and I am getting this error after starting pipenv shell and then runserver.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "C:\Users\norchi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.utils.version import get_version
  File "C:\Users\norchi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import datetime
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datetime'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Here are some things I tried:

- I tried updating the PATH vars and I also added a PYTHONPATH = C:\Users\norchi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32
- I installed django using pipenv and using pip outside of the virtual environment.
- python show django outputs that the path for django is C:\Users\norchi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages

Comment: hit pip freeze and check weather django is there

Comment: I am getting an import error on runpy